# Matching two columns in one sheet to two columns in another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function, countif

I need to assign a status to a row based on a VLOOKUP query between two worksheets. The problem is that the identifier is not always unique. However, the identifier + a date value should be unique. I wanted to use:

```
=VLOOKUP(A3&H3,'OtherSheet'!D:E,1,FALSE)
```

with A3 being the identifier and H3 being the corresponding date. D in the other sheet is the identifier and E is the date column. However, I keep getting #N/A.

Does this mean that there are no matches with the "identifier+date" or is Excel looking for "identifier+date" in either column D or E? If the latter is true, how can I let Excel concatenate D and E when matching to the search pattern?

Comment: As a workaround I have created a column in both sheets to concatenate the columns to create a unique identifier. It would be nice if I could reach the same result with "helper columns"

Comment: You can use Index/Match or Index/Sumproduct to do a multiple-criteria lookup. [This post](http://yoursumbuddy.com/index-sumproduct-or-index-match-for-multiple-criteria-lookups/) might be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

There's work around without using CTRL+Shift+Enter.

Use this formula that will match A3 in D column of othersheet and H3 with the date in column E of the othersheet.

```
=INDEX(OtherSheet!F:F,MATCH(1,INDEX((OtherSheet!D:D=A3)*(OtherSheet!E:E=H3),),0))
```

The formula will return data from F column of OtherSheet.
You can modify the range `OtherSheet!F:F` as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

That formula is looking to find A3 concatenated with H3 (identifier&date) in `OtherSheet` ColumnD that contains only identifiers, so will inevitably fail. Yes, Excel is looking for “identifier+date” in column D.

Excel will happily concatenate A3 with H3 ‘on the fly’ (within a formula) but will not so happily concatenate `OtherSheet` ColumnD and ColumnE values in the same way. The conventional solution, because usually simplest in a case like this, is to prepare for the VLOOKUP by adding a helper column that concatenates the D and E values while preserving these in the same row as the value sought.

Because VLOOKUP will only look to the right this is usually a column that is added to the left of the value being searched for, so say either in C or by insertion of a column immediately to the right of C. However, since you are only checking a single column the location is not critical. You might add this (in `OtherSheet`) as ColumnZ, with a formula such as:

```
=D2&E2
```

copied down to suit`*`. Again because you are only checking a single column it does not matter which row such a formula is placed in.

However, because only checking whether A3&H3 exists in `OtherSheet` a simple alternative may be to apply COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS(OtherSheet!D:D,A3,OtherSheet!E:E,H3)
```

Any result other than `0` from this should indicate that the combination being tested for exists in `OtherSheet` – without need for a helper column.

`*` Depending on the format of your identifiers it is possible that concatenation may introduce ambiguity. For example ID90 concatenated with 11/1/15 may not be distinguishable from ID901 concatenated with 1/1/15, so it may be advisable if taking this approach to introduce a delimiter, in both the VLOOKUP formula (say `A3&"|"&H3` rather than just `A3&H3`) and therefore also in the helper column, say `=D2&"|"&E2`.

Answer (score 0):

You likely would want to use Index/Match instead.  Vlookup is tricky when it comes to searches for multiple things.  Here's the way you would use Index/Match:

Without knowing how your spreadsheet is set up, here's how you could do it:

If I understand correctly, you want to use A3 to find the match in `OtherSheet!D`, and H3's match in `OtherSheet!E`.  Index match is perfect for this.  Instead of vLookup, use

`=Index(OtherSheet!D:D&","&Text(OtherSheet!E:E,"mm-dd-yyyy"),Match(A3&H3,OtherSheet!D&OtherSheet!E,0))`, and enter with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.

What the `Index()` will return is the concatenated Identifier and Date, separated with a comma.  If, though, you have a table like this:

[image]

That index/match formula will return "Batman".  The index to return is the named range G2:G5.  You're looking for a match on A1 (the Identifier) and B1 (the Date), then you're searching for (in the order you just put) the Identifier to be in the range E2:E5, and the Date to be in F2:F5.  When there's  a match for both, it returns the name in G2:G5.

Here's a link to [a site on](http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/) using Index/Match, and [another](http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/how-use-index-match-instead-vlookup) and its advantages over vlookup.