# Copy Data From Separate Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am wanting to bring a heap of data from a sheet in one file into another file, but only if certain criteria are met. There are around 10,000 rows, so just a bit too much to do manually.

So the source file is called VDW-December-2017.csv and the sheet is called VDW.

One part of the formula seeks to match the dates which are in column A of both source and target - `=IF(J2=‘[VDW-December-2017.csv]VDW’!J2`.

The second part of the formula needs the data in column J to match, so `=IF(A2=‘[VDW-December-2017.csv]VDW’!A2`

So only if both of those things are true, the the result will be what is in column P of the source sheet.

Unless there is a better way, my aim is to have the formula be in column P in my target sheet and the code would be saying pretty much this:

If the dates in column A match and the names in column J match, then the answer will be what is in column P, if that makes sense. if the answer is no, nothing is to happen

I have managed to get the individual sections of code and assume it may be an IF AND formula, but am not sure exactly what to do, as I don't want anything to happen if the answer is false. Only if it is true, then copy the data fro P in the source to P in the target.

This was the code I came up with just to test if I can at least get a result, but nothing, so not sure I am on the right track.

`=IF(AND(A2=‘[VDW-December-2017.csv]VDW’!A2, J2=‘[VDW-December-2017.csv]VDW’!J2), True, False)`

I even tried just using the IF formula just to see if I have it right in sections, but no result

`=IF(A2=‘[VDW-December-2017.csv]VDW’!A2, True, False)`

Again, I am not after a True or False answer here, so maybe IF is not the way to go either, as all I need is the data in any cell in row P to be copied to the corresponding row in column P in the target, if both the date and name match in both source and target

Any help gladly accepted

cheers

Answer (score 0):

## '1 Sheet' in CSV

In cell `P2` use the following formula:

> ```
> =IF(A2=INT('VDW-December-2017.csv'!A2),'VDW-December-2017.csv'!P2,"")
> ```

## EDIT

My new understanding of your problem is the following:
You are trying to match the values of columns **A** and **J** in target sheet to the values of columns **A** and **J** of source sheet, and when match is found, in column **P** in target sheet return the value of column **P** (in the 'found' row) of source sheet. And there is the date issue, which I previously solved with `INT`, **above** and in [Just 'Imagine' IF in Conditional Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54389428/conditional-formatting-excel-based-on-date-in-another-cell/54847769#54847769).

The new information lead me to [**Hellboy**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4527488/hellboy)'s brilliant [**ANSWER**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023360/matching-two-columns-in-one-sheet-to-two-columns-in-another/48377277#48377277) to the question [Matching two columns in one sheet to two columns in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023360/matching-two-columns-in-one-sheet-to-two-columns-in-another)
, which let me produce the following formulas, for cell `P2`:

### ISERROR (Excel 2003)

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(1,INDEX((INT('VDW-December-2017.csv'!A$2:A$10000)=A2)*('VDW-December-2017.csv'!J$2:J$10000=J2),),0)),"",INDEX('VDW-December-2017.csv'!P$2:P$10000,MATCH(1,INDEX((INT('VDW-December-2017.csv'!A$2:A$10000)=A2)*('VDW-December-2017.csv'!J$2:J$10000=J2),),0)))
```

---

### IFERROR

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('VDW-December-2017.csv'!P$2:P$10000,MATCH(1,INDEX((INT('VDW-December-2017.csv'!A$2:A$10000)=A2)*('VDW-December-2017.csv'!J$2:J$10000=J2),),0)),"")
```

---

**Adjust the 10000s to what ever you need.**

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. No result with that. I am wondering whether it is in the format of the date cells in each, as I had this issue before with a different formula and it required =IF(TEXT(A2,”dd/mm/yyyy” and so on to extract the date correctly and match them. The format of the date cells in the target is simply Date, with the sample showing 6/12/17 and so on. The format of the date in the source cell is Custom and is d/m/yyyy hh:mm

Comment: Just so you know, I even tried changing the format of the source date column to just Date and pasting that code again, but still no result

Comment: @Why don't you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54389428/conditional-formatting-excel-based-on-date-in-another-cell/54847769#54847769), where I address your date issue, and adjust the formula accordingly. I did it myself. Try now.

Comment: Cheers, that INT works well sorting the date match. I have tried to add the second part to the formula, which seeks to make sure the names also match. They are in column J. When I added the second part, the message says too many arguments, though to my eye it seems right

<code>=IF(AND(A2=INT('VDW-December-2017.csv'!A2, J2='VDW-December-2017.csv'!J2),'VDW-December-2017.csv'!P2,"")</code>

To me this says, IF A2 and the source A2 match AND J2 and the source J2 match, then the result is source P2, otherwise nothing. What have I mucked up there?

Comment: I have also just realised where this is all going to fall over. Not all rows will align, unfortunately. The source document has around 10,000 rows and the target only around 3,000, so only around a third of the listings from the source are in the target; those in the target just need the info from the corresponding cell in row P. So, there will be many times where the matching date and name are in different rows. 

So your original formula would work well when the rows align, but it seems that this may well need to be some sort of lookup formula.

Comment: As I sad, around a third of the ones will match date and name, but the data in the source will include many superfluous entries. 

So I may not have worded what I needed correctly initially, but the idea is IF date and name in source match date and name in the target, then the result will be P from the corresponding row in the source. The INT will still help to sort the date format issue, but it is about matching data in columns A (date)  & J (names) for the result to happen.

My apologies for not saying this initially

Comment: @honkin: I've done some research and finally (hopefully) got you the answer you were looking for. Check out the EDIT.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. No result with that if it is positive, but if I add a word to it to check, that word show, so it is only working for the negative side. 

I put the formula just into one cell to check. I also did a manual search just to find matching names and dates; the cell A44 in the target and A534 in the source have the same date, cell J44 target and J534 source have the same name, yet the data in P534 (100) does not come across, so something is just not quite there. The result remains blank, unless I add a word for the negative answer rather than ""

Comment: @honkin: Why don't you copy J44 to J534 and A44 to A534 to make sure they are the same? Did you try both formulas? I have only tested the first formula.

Comment: No, had only seen the one formula you posted, but just did the other one and it worked fine; at least on the one row. I will just test it by pasting it in the entire column and see what it does, but it looks really promising. Once again, thanks so much. Just let me check it through the entire doc, but I'm hopeful. regards

Comment: OK, that tests absolutely perfectly for that column...P. 

Is there any reason why just changing column P to column Z would stop it from working? There are about 3 columns of data to come across, so just planned to put a slightly different formula in each column. The first worked 100% for column P. I kept the formula the same but where it had !P$2:P$10000 I simply changed that to be !Z$2:Z$10000 but nothing was copied across, though the number 8 is in the cell to be copied.

Comment: nah, all tests OK. Maybe in copying and pasting it changed some characters, usually ". This time I copied a cell from where it was working to the new cell and changed P to Z. All works beautifully. 
Thanks so much for all your help.....once again. This has saved hours of work